# HTACCESS Can't Redirect to a Subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

Good Day! I am just new in setting up a wordpress server in Linux Ubuntu 
My Wordpress directory is in

```
/var/www/html/
```

and I just want only to redirect it from the wordpress folder
the .htaccess file Ive created is this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /wordpress [L,R=301]
```

but it didnt work and when I try to test it in the browser only directories can view?

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

It working now!!
Just Add this code in apache

> ```
>     <Directory /var/www/>
>             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>             AllowOverride All
>             Order allow,deny
>             allow from all
>     </Directory>
> ```

And it will fix it :D